# Scroll to top button is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I have a problem with scroll to top button support in IE. I am obliged to use only native JS, and no libraries and frameworks. I am struggling to understand why it is not working, not even adding a class to be shown, not speaking for the functionality of scrolling itself. I checked the caniuse, and it seems like everything should work fine, but it is not working. Would be very grateful for any clues.

```js
// Scroll to top button logic
var scrollToTopBtn = document.querySelector(".scrollToTopBtn");
var rootElement = document.documentElement;
var TOGGLE_RATIO = 0.20;

function handleScroll() {
  var scrollTotal = rootElement.scrollHeight - rootElement.clientHeight;
  if ((rootElement.scrollTop / scrollTotal) > TOGGLE_RATIO) {
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.add("showBtn");
  } else {
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.remove("showBtn");
  }
};

function scrollToTop() {
  rootElement.scrollTop = 0;
};

scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);

window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

```css
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
.content { height: 900px; background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</main>
<button class="scrollToTopBtn showBtn">Top</button>
```

Here is a fiddle for testing https://jsfiddle.net/sorqefz9/

Comment: Consider using [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) instead?

Comment: What happens instead? Is there any error message given?

Comment: @evolutionxbox scrollTo is not supported in IE

Comment: @NicoHaase the thing is, that IE does not show any errors, it simply do not add class to my button, and scroll is not working at all. It is strange behavior. Though in other browsers it works correctly as expected.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] and what IE are we talking about? IE 11, 8, ...?

Comment: @william_eduards `scrollTo` is supported in IE, just not the smooth scrolling option https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: @Andreas added a fiddle. Speaking about versions, I need support at least from 9 - 11 IE versions.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you, I will implement it. But seems like it is still not the problem. The problem is, that the class add is not working, and function handleScroll() is somehow not being fired.

Comment: The example in your question (on jsfiddle) works with IE11

Comment: @Andreas could you please share, how you tested it?

Comment: @Andreas I mean js fiddle is not working in IE the same as stackoverflow. I mean you got the code out of fiddle and tested it on real browser?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `scroll` which is basically the same ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)):

```
function scrollToTop() {
    window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
};
```

```js
var scrollToTopBtn;
var rootElement;
var TOGGLE_RATIO;

function handleScroll() {
  var scrollTotal = rootElement.scrollHeight - rootElement.clientHeight;
  if ((rootElement.scrollTop / scrollTotal) > TOGGLE_RATIO) {
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.add("showBtn");
  } else {
    scrollToTopBtn.classList.remove("showBtn");
  }
};

function scrollToTop() {
  window.scroll({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  // Scroll to top button logic
  scrollToTopBtn = document.querySelector(".scrollToTopBtn");
  rootElement = document.documentElement;
  TOGGLE_RATIO = 0.20;

  scrollToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

```css
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
.content { height: 900px; background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</main>
<button class="scrollToTopBtn showBtn">Top</button>
```

Comment: The problem is, that I am not struggling with the scroll event, but mostly with the fact, that the class is not being added, the same as click event is not working, and I have no idea why it happens..

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a `DOMContentLoaded` or similar event? See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchor element.

at top of page:
`<div id="top"></div>`
button:
`<a href="#top">Go to Top</a>`
then style the hyperlink